# JavaFX protect FXML/CSS files?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

if i build a JavaFX-Application, that is made with SceneBuilder and contains *.fxml/*.css-files, theoretically everyone could modify these files, if i'm right about this. Is there a way to protect these files to make it impossible for strangers to modify/view them? I know i could style my application with the built in functions but i personally want to avoid this.

Comment: can't answer but wondering why? can't be _that_ secret .. an elaborate custom css maybe, but fxml?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot prevent the user from gaining access to your css/fxml file; you just can make it difficult for them. At some point JavaFX will need to see the unencrypted version of the file contents. At that time they'd just need to gain access to the internals of the right parts of JavaFX and they could produce an CSS file that does exactly the same as your css file. The same is true for fxml: The user would just need to replace the `FXMLLoader.class` file with a custom one and write the content read to a file. This is not too hard since openjfx is, well open...

Comment: You could sign your jar though which would allow you to verify that the contents of the jar have not been modified; if you provide a suitable security policy could block the execution, assuming the user cooperates and uses this secutrity policy. (I assume you deploy the app as jar containing the resources.)

Comment: Use [Amazon AppStream](https://aws.amazon.com/appstream2/) to stream the app from the amazon servers to the client.

Comment: When you take your application to production, ou have to render the app to JAR file or EXE File. Then no one cant access your fxml codes